# Identifier 'x' has already been declared at <anonymous>:1:1

Tags: javascript, this, bind

So I'm just learning how to code, and I'm working my way through a beginner's guide to Javascript and had a ?.

I am on the 'This and bind' section, so I am trying to bind an object to a function and I keep getting the following error: Identifier 'coordinates1' has already been declared at 
anonymous:1:1

I have ran into this same error message quite a few times in my practice. My code looks like below. Any help is greatly appreciated. I know this is probably a simple, silly error, so I Thank you for any answers!

```
let coordinates1 = {
    x: 45.0,
    y: 22.0
}

let coordinates2 = {
    x: 12.6,
    y: 22.7
}

function coordinateStatement (){
    console.log ('The coordinates are ' + this.x + ', ' + this.y)
}

console.log(coordinateStatement())
console.log(coordinateStatement.bind(coordinates1)())
console.log(coordinateStatement.bind(coordinates2)())
```

Comment: The code you posted only results in that error message when you execute it multiple times in the same context. How exactly do you execute it?

Answer (score 1):

`let` and `const` variables, by design, can't be redeclared. When you write console code, you're writing it all in the same scope, causing variables to be redecleard.
Change `let` to `var` or reload the page to solve the error.